# What's missing from the Xbox 360 version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I recently purchased Minecraft for my Xbox and I have been playing through it.  I've started looking through the Minecraft wiki and have noticed that some things aren't in the Xbox version.

However, I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of everything that's not in the Xbox version.

What elements of Minecraft Java Edition are not in the Xbox 360 version?